# JQuery animate div "like" a Zoom

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I can never get these to work - sorry - but I I am trying to animate on a mouse over then "re-animate" on a mouse out.  I can never get `$('#xyz').hover(function(){'something',function(){'somethingelse'});` to work.  Hope you guys can help.

What I am trying to do is animate + and - 20px (top and left) on some absolutely positioned divs and then add 40px to the width height returning to the original position/width/height on mouse out.  I haven't even got to the css widths/heights yet ....

Here is my code (which is wrong - well it must be as it doesn't work :-) )

```
  $('.box').hover(function(){

 $(this).animate({'top':'-20','left':'-20'},function(){

   $(this).animate({'top':'20','left':'20' });


      });
```

Help really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you missed the second peren in the first `animate` call. Not sure if it's a copying error or if that's your problem.

Comment: @zzzzBov  - that's my problem, not a typo thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nesting in the wrong places ;)

```
 $('.box').hover(
      function(){
           $(this).animate({'top':'-20px','left':'-20px'});
     },
      function(){
        $(this).animate({'top':'20px','left':'20px' });
      }
 );
```

The way you had your nesting, you were using the callback functionality of the animate method. So you were calling the second animation once the first ended, and not when the mouse moved out..

---

**Update**

Additionally you need to provide a unit for the calculations you perform so add a `px` next to your numbers, and if you want it to change in regards to the current position the use the `+=` and `-=`

```
 $('.box').hover(
      function(){
          $(this).animate({'top':'-=20px','left':'-=20px', 'height':'+=40px'});
     },
      function(){
        $(this).animate({'top':'+=20px','left':'+=20px', 'height':'-=40px' });
      }
 );
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/e3h43/1/

Comment: @Gaby - thanks for this/that works a treat with one exception (not your fault) - my fault in not really asking the right question. What i really ned it +/-20px from the div's position (I have 6 of them) so going for "top:-20" or "top:+20" works on the first but not the others as they all go "top +/-20" - any idea how to do this with "offset?".  All the divs are position absolute inside a "relative" wrapper"

Comment: @Gaby - PERFECT -  pls hlp me learn (if you will) what is difference between '-20px' and '-=20px' etc?

Comment: @Russell, the `-=` and `+=` mimic the relevant javascript shorthand operators (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_Operators). `-= 10px` means subtract `10px` from the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turning my comment into an answer:

You made a typo, you missed the closing peren after the first `animate` call.